# How to get attributes of running Java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have that code:

Main class:

```
public class myTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new myThreadClass("thread 1"), "thread 1");
        t1.start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(glownyTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(glownyTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

 }
}
```

My Thread class

```
public class myThreadClass extends Thread {

private HashSet<String> texts = new HashSet<String>();

public myThreadClass(String id) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {}

@Override
public void run() {
     ... collecting Strings into my hashSet ....
}

public HashSet<String> getTexts() {
    return texts;
}
}
```

I've tried to call

```
t1.getTexts();
```

in my Main Class after starting the thread, but it doesn't work - I want to access texts hashSet from my Main Class level. How to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'attributes'?

Comment: What [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) constructor ist that where you can pass a `Thread` instance as first parameter? Your class `myThreadClass` is extending Thread, schould it be implementing `Runnable` instead? How do you fill `texts` ? may be it is just empty when you access it and you need to wait till something is in there or poll it inside a loop...

Comment: Hmm, when i Just did myThreadClass t2 = new MyThreadClass()... - I can call my function, so it is. : )

Comment: Please provide an compileable/runnable code example. `t1` is of type `Thread` with does not know about `texts` and `MyThreadClasS` does not have a default constructor.

Comment: @A4L Unfortunately, `Thread` implements `Runnable`. So any instance of `Thread` could be passed to the constructor of another.

Comment: @TimBender, Ah yes... I should have looked a couple of lines above the constuctors summary in the javadoc... thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a method belonging to your type `myThreadClass` then you need to be sure to declare the variable as an instance of that type.

Like so:

```
myThreadClass t1 = new myThreadClass("thread 1");
```

There are some problems you are likely to run into ... like needing to `join` the `Thread` to be sure that it finishes populating the `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not abuse the `Thread` class for your program logic. You should build your custom `Runnable` implementation, which you pass into `Thread`'s constructor. That way the separation of concerns between thread control and your program logic will be more apparent to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create reference of myThreadClass

```
myThreadClass t1
```

or

cast your reference to myThreadClass like

```
((myThreadClass )t1).getTexts();
```

This will work!!

Answer (score 0):

```
myThreadClass t1 = new myThreadClass("thread 1");
t1.start()
try{
t1.join();
t1.getTexts();
}catch(InterruptedException x){
 ....
}
```

Usually the first letter of the class name is capital.